# Video mute/unmute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, video, mute

I'd like to make a mute/unmute button in jQuery. I've done some searching on Stackoverflow and this is what I managed to do so far:

```
$("video").prop('muted', true);

$("#mute-video").click( function (){
    if( $("video").prop('muted', true) )
    {
        $("video").prop('muted', false);
    }

    else {
    $("video").prop('muted', true);
    }

});
```

but for some reason it's only able to unmute, not to mute back.

Any idea what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Code seems ok to me, have you checked if there is any errors in console

Comment: If you want to unmute your video: `$("video").prop('muted', false);`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you're doing `if( $("video").prop('muted', true) )` you're both setting the property to `true` and then ask if it's true.

Changing the condition to `if( $("video").prop('muted') )` solves the problem - [Here's](http://jsbin.com/higor/1/edit?html,output) an example.

Also note this will work on all videos on a page so if you have more than one player it might get confusing.

Comment: Ronny, big thnx, that worked!
If it comes to "video", I used it as a temporary solution - now I checked with the video ID and it works as well.

Comment: I came across this post and shortened the code:
`$("video").prop('muted', !$("video").prop('muted')))`