# Mute button on video slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, video

I have created a video in a slider, in order for there to not be a start and stop button. 
But I would like to add a mute button, so if there is a video with sounds, then the user will be able to mute it.
Does anyone please know how can add a mute button to the video in the slider.

Video here: http://wearecrunch.net/dasket/test/

Comment: and your source code is? I for one will not visit that URL. If you're asking how to do that, then the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:: you need to create a button in your HTML, change the CSS to make it looks nicer and then add the JS as controller
I don't want to go too deep to modify your code, since it is in WordPress, but some thing just like:
    Mute
And then for the JS:

```
$("#mute").click( function (){
if( $("video").prop('muted') ){
    $("video").prop('muted', false);
    $("#mute").html('unmuted');
}
else {
    $("video").prop('muted', true);
    $("#mute").html('muted');
}
});
```

I found this question may help you:
[Video mute/unmute with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852284/video-mute-unmute-with-jquery)