# Mute Background Video with Divi Theme on Wordpress

Tags: jquery

I have a looping background image on my website via the Divi theme.

I cannot mute the video through the theme functionality at all.

I've tried to use this:

```
$('video').prop('volume', 0)
$('video').prop('muted', true)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video mute/unmute with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852284/video-mute-unmute-with-jquery)

Comment: My problem is different than the other solution. I don't want to create a button, I just want to mute the video. That solution does not work for me with this theme. If I'm missing something, please explain....

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
(function($){
  $('video').prop('muted', true)
})(jQuery);
```

WordPress use jQuery and this solves compatibility problems with other libraries

You can use javascript without jquery.